# Kill SimpleHTTPServer process which is started in background with subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, simplehttpserver

I am trying to kill `SimpleHTTPServer` in my script.
Manually the command is working fine.

```
Starting SimpleHTTPServer in background:
-bash-4.2$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080 &
[1] 26345

Verifying SimpleHTTPServer process:
-bash-4.2$ ps -ef | grep SimpleHTTPServer
x  26345 20169  0 17:44 pts/21   00:00:00 python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080

Killing SimpleHTTPServer:
-bash-4.2$ kill -9 `ps -ef | grep SimpleHTTPServer | grep 8080 | awk '{print $2}'`

Verifying SimpleHTTPServer is killed or not:
-bash-4.2$ ps -ef | grep SimpleHTTPServer
x  26356 20169  0 17:45 pts/21   00:00:00 grep --color=auto SimpleHTTPServer
```

Same thing in script is not working. I am using `subprocess.Popen`.

```
subprocess.Popen(["kill", "-9", "`ps -ef | grep SimpleHTTPServer | grep 8080 | awk '{print $2}'`"])
(Pdb++) kill: cannot find process "`ps -ef | grep SimpleHTTPServer | grep 8080 | awk '{print $2}'`"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use a shell backtick, around a shell pipeline, in that `kill` command. But you're trying to do it without `shell=True`. You can't do that.

You can build a `sh` command line and run that with `shell=True`, but that's usually a bad idea.

The `subprocess`  docs on [Replacing Older Functions with the `subprocess` Module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-older-functions-with-the-subprocess-module) show how you can do the same things in Python that you were using the shell for. That's a better idea, but a bit of work.

But the simplest thing to do is just not call any of this stuff.

- You don't need the `ps|grep|grep|awk` to find the PID of the process, because you `Popen`ed the process, so it's just `proc.pid`.
- And you don't need the `kill` either, because you still have that `Popen` object around, so you can just call `kill`, `terminate`, or `send_signal` on it.

Comment: I want to kill `SimpleHTTPServer` which was started earlier, not the one which I start after killing. I want it to be alive till the next script run.

Comment: @npatel OK, then do either of the other two versions I explained first.